# Eclipse skip proxy for an IP address

Tags: eclipse, proxy, fiddler

I'm developing an Android application and I need to capture data sent from the emulator. I installed fiddler and launched the emulator using

```
-http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Now the problem is, my Android application needs to connect to a server deployed on my local system. It is not able to do that (I think it is because of the proxy configured). Is it possible to skip the proxy for a particular IP address? Could you please let me know?

Comment: Why don't you use hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about Android programming but based on your title "Eclipse skip proxy for an IP address", I suggest if you like to bypass any ip from proxy in eclipse settings, then add the bypass ip address in eclipse->preferences->General->Network Connections->Proxy Bypass...
(Plz ignore if this is not what you need :))

Answer (score 0):

The way you start your emulator means that ALL TCP connections will be forced through your proxy (0:8888).
I'm not aware about any options to bypass the proxy setting but maybe there is an undocumented environment variable you could dig out. (Documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120613232530/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)).

Your issue is that Fiddler excepts all traffic, please note I've never used it.
You'd need Fiddler to allow the TCP traffic to your webserver (the one your app talks to).

Solution a)
I can't test this for you but you should take a look at **"IE should bypass Fiddler"** [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081119143809/http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/OptionsUI.asp).

With a little bit luck it might work to enter your webserver URL in there.

Solution b)
Not that easy to set up. You could set up a second HTTP proxy and use a firewall like iptables to route your webserver traffic (the one you want to bypass Fiddler) through your second HTTP proxy. [SQUID](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxies can do that (in transparent proxy mode).
Quite some work but it should do the trick.

Solution c)
You said you want to capture your data. Fiddler does a lot more than that.
If all you wish to do is analyze your data then you do not need the HTTP proxy at all.
Get [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or tcpdump, it can capture and record your traffic.

Solution d)
You need to modify the Android emulator and add proxy bypass support to it.

Solution e)
Use some sort of port forwarding firewall (instead of the squid approach) and run a simple "Polipo" HTTP proxy on another port.
[Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/) is easy to set up and the HTTP proxy protocol should be simple (encapsulated requests) enough to allow a port-forwarded splitting without any connection troubles.

I can't see another solution.